# Actualizar registros relacionados - Laravel 8 Livewire

Tags: laravel, php7, crud, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

actualmente me encuentro haciendo un CRUD con registros relacionados en Laravel 8 usando Livewire. La relacion es hasMany y no puedo editarlos o agregarlos usando la relacion. Pero cuando en otros modelos con relacion hasOne no tuve ningun problema en hacerlo.

Modelo License:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\Personal;
use App\Models\Renovation;

class License extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'licenses';

    protected $fillable = ['id','personal_id', 'resolution', 'identification', 'date_registration', 'renovation_id'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function personal(){
        return $this->hasOne(Personal::class, 'id', 'personal_id');
    }

    public function renovations(){
        return $this->hasMany(Renovation::class, 'id', 'renovation_id');
    }
}
```

Modelo Renovation:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\Models\License;

class Renovation extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['year_paid', 'iva_condition', 'status'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';

    public function license(){
        return $this->belongsTo(License::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

Los metodos estan en el componente de Livewire:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use App\Models\License;
use App\Models\Personal;
use App\Models\Renovation;

class TbLicense extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $search, $license_id, $personal_id, $resolution, $identification, $date_registration, $renovation_id;

    public  $year_paid, $iva_condition, $status;

    public $action  = "store";
    public $tabla   = "Matricula";

    public function render()
    {
        $items = Personal::all();

        return view('livewire.tb-license',[
            'licenses' => License::with('renovations','personal')
            ->where('identification', 'LIKE', "%{$this->search}%")
            ->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', "%{$this->search}%")
            ->paginate(5)
        ])->with(compact('items'));
    }

    public function store()
    {
        $this->validate([
            'personal_id'       => 'required',
            'resolution'        => 'required',
            'identification'    => 'required',
            'date_registration' => 'required|date',
            'year_paid'         => 'required|date',
            'iva_condition'     => 'required',
            'status'            => 'required',
        ]);

        Renovation::create([
            'year_paid'      => $this->year_paid,
            'iva_condition'  => $this->iva_condition,
            'status'         => $this->status
        ]);

        $data = Renovation::latest('id')->first();
        
        License::create([
            'personal_id'       => $this->personal_id,
            'resolution'        => $this->resolution,
            'identification'    => $this->identification,
            'date_registration' => $this->date_registration,
            'renovation_id'     => $data->id
        ]);
        
        $this->reset(['search', 'action', 'personal_id', 'resolution', 'identification', 'date_registration', 'renovation_id', 'year_paid', 'iva_condition', 'status']);
    }
    public function edit(License $License)
    {
        $this->resolution        = $License->resolution        ;
        $this->identification    = $License->identification    ;
        $this->date_registration = $License->date_registration ;
        $this->renovation_id     = $License->renovation_id     ;
        $this->license_id        = $License->id                ;

        $this->year_paid         = $License->renovations->year_paid         ;
        $this->iva_condition     = $License->renovations->iva_condition     ;
        $this->status            = $License->renovations->status            ;
        $this->renovation_id     = $License->renovations->id                ;

        $this->action = "update";
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $license = License::find($this->license_id);

        $license->update([
            'resolution'        => $this->resolution       ,
            'identification'    => $this->identification   ,
            'date_registration' => $this->date_registration,
            'renovation_id'     => $this->renovation_id    
        ]);

        $license->renovations = Renovation::find($this->renovation_id);

        $license->renovations->update([
            'year_paid'         => $this->year_paid    ,
            'iva_condition'     => $this->iva_condition,
            'status'            => $this->status       
        ]);

        $this->reset(['search', 'action', 'personal_id', 'resolution', 'identification', 'date_registration', 'renovation_id', 'year_paid', 'iva_condition', 'status']);

    }

    public function destroy(License $License)
    {
        $License->delete();
    }

    public function default()
    {
        $this->reset(['search', 'action', 'resolution', 'identification', 'date_registration', 'renovation_id', 'year_paid', 'iva_condition', 'status']);
    }
}
```

La migracion de License es la siguiente:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateLicensesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('licenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->unsignedBigInteger('personal_id')->nullable();
            $table->string('resolution');
            $table->bigInteger('identification');
            $table->date('date_registration');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('renovation_id')->nullable();

            $table->foreign('personal_id')->references('id')->on('personals');
            $table->foreign('renovation_id')->references('id')->on('renovations');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('licenses');
    }
}
```

Y la migracion de Renovation es la siguiente:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateRenovationsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('renovations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();

            $table->date('year_paid');
            $table->string('iva_condition');
            $table->string('status');

            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('renovations');
    }
}
```

No se en que estoy fallando pero usando la misma forma con dos modelos pero con una relacion hasOne funciona de maravilla. ¿En que estoy fallando? ¿Podrian ayudarme?

Comment: Cuál es el problema?, decir que no funciona no da indicio claro entonces por favor explica a detalle que ocurre cuando intentas actualizar

Comment: dices que no logras correr la migración?

Comment: El problema es que al usar el metodo Store no se añaden los registros relacionados. La idea es que primero se cree un registro en una tabla y relacionarlo con otro registro que se crea en otra tabla.

Comment: En este caso tengo un formulario que pide los datos de la licencia y de renovación. La idea que a la hora de crearse la licencia se relacione con esa renovación. Como una licencia puede tener varias renovaciones es que la relacion es de 1 a muchos.

Comment: La idea es despues crear otro método donde solo se busque la licencia y luego se le agregue la renovación.

Comment: Tu estructura relacional indica que cada licencia referencia una renovación, y no a la inversa. 10 licencias podrían tener el mismo renovation_id. En el modelo renovations dices que pertenecen a license con el campo id. Esto significaría que el ID de cada renovación referencia una licencia, Debiera ser, en cambio, license_id, y crear una FK referenciando la PK de license.

Comment: Sin las vistas de livewire, poco te puedo ayudar :( hay pequeños defectos en tu código, pero son, sobre todo, problemas de buenas prácticas

Answer (score 2):

Como dije en mi comentario, tu estructura de base de datos está invertida. En tu modelo cada licencia pertenece a una renovación a través de `renovation_id`, en circunstancias que cada renovación debiese pertenecer a una licencia a través de un campo `license_id` que hoy no existe.

Cuando declaras que las renovaciones dependen de una licencia via

```
public function renovations(){
    return $this->hasMany(Renovation::class);
}
```

y la licencia de cada renovación como

```
public function license(){
    return $this->belongsTo(License::class);
}
```

[La convención](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#authentication-quickstart) lleva a que por debajo se asocien respectivamente con algo como

```
-- renovaciones de una licencia
SELECT * FROM renovations JOIN license ON license.id = renovation.license 
   WHERE license.id = ?

-- licencia de cada renovación
SELECT * FROM license JOIN renovation ON license.id = renovation.license 
   WHERE renovation.id = ?
```

Tu definición, en cambio

```
    return $this->hasMany(Renovation::class, 'id', 'renovation_id');
```

significa

```
    SELECT * FROM license JOIN renovation ON license.renovation_id = renovation.id
      WHERE license.id = ?
```

cómo podría esa consulta arrojar varias renovaciones si un registro en la tabla de licencias tiene un `id` único y ese único posible registro debe calzar con la llave primaria de `renovations`?

Debieses cambiar la definición de License quitando

```
       $table->unsignedBigInteger('renovation_id')->nullable();
       $table->foreign('renovation_id')->references('id')->on('renovations');
```

Y a su vez la de renovation añadiendo

```
       $table->unsignedBigInteger('license_id')->nullable();
       $table->foreign('license_id')->references('id')->on('license');
```

El resto de tu definición no lo analicé, pero si se presenta un problema en otro punto del flujo debiera ser materia de otra pregunta.